# Regex, match "private function", "public function" or just "function"

Tags: regex

I am getting some problems while trying to use this regex:

```
(public +function|private +function|function) +([a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*) *\\(([0-9a-zA-Z_$, ]*)\\) *{(.*)}
```

For some reason, $1 and $2 are returning the same value.

The target string is:

```
public function messenger(text){
    sendMsg(text);
}
private function sendMsg(text){
    alert(text);
}
```

How can I fix that? By the way, I am using Javascript.

EDIT:

Ok, the answers worked, but the problem now is that the last paramenter is returning "sendMsg(text); } private function sendMsg(text){ alert(text);}", it is not stopping in the first "}"

Comment: Since there's only a single set of parentheses, $2 won't be defined. What are the groups you want to capture?

Comment: The rest of the code isn't posted, I'll update it

Comment: the new problem deserves it's own question, since it's unrelated to this one.

Comment: Ok, sorry, already made another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually, this was wrong, or at least misleading

see [Regex is capturing the whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588994/regex-is-capturing-the-whole-string/2589470#2589470) for the improved version

| has a very low priority, you probably want

(public +function)|(private +function)|(function)

or even

(public|private +)?function

As a side note, regexp is not the best tool for parsing programming languages' grammars. For example, a regexp solution will fail on something like

var foo = "private function";

Comment: Your second regexp is missing a space: it will match "publicfunction" but not "public function".

Comment: I am using javascript, there is no other way in it to parse a language

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this be what you're looking for?

```
 (public |private +)?function
```

This will check for either public, private, and the `?` signifies those are optional so only `function` will work too. Just tested it using regexpal.com

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(public | private)?\sfunction
```

Beware tho, this could match: `private private public private public function function`. If you can assure that the code is "clean" and doesn't have this kind of scenarios then use it.